# How to get the data from word file along with the image and send email via SMTP in Python

Tags: python, smtp, mime, ionos

I am using python and below is the image from word file that i need to get to send email via SMTP.

So far i am able to get ONLY text and send it with a success but not the image.

[image]

I have tried many things including `MIMEImage` and what not. I can't even paste my code here now as it will make no sense. Please help me out. Last when I tried to combine the body string with the image `as_string` it gave me the error for being too long due to encoding.

P.S. I want to be able to run it a loop and sending 3 4 emails. I am successful in sending the text ONLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Example
You can use [`docx2txt`](https://openbase.com/python/docx2txt) module to Extract the  Text & Images drom a word document

```
import os , docx2txt
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


# Extract the text from the file
# Extract the images from the file
images = []


# The text variable contains the text from the Word document & the 'img' contains 
# the Extracted images from the Document

text = docx2txt.process("example.docx", './img/') # create the folder before hand


directory = './img/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    images.append(f)


# Create the email message
sender= 'sender@gmail.com'
receiver = 'receiver@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Example Email'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

# Attach the text data and Hyperlink
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
msg.attach(MIMEText(u'<a href="www.Your Link to the WebSite.com">Tiktok4Realtors.com</a>','html'))

# Attach the images
for img in images:
    with open(img, 'rb') as f:
        img_data = f.read()
    image = MIMEApplication(img_data, _subtype='png')
    image.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=img)
    msg.attach(image)

# Send the email
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()# to enable security
server.login(sender, 'senders pasword')
server.sendmail(sender,receiver, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: how to add the hyperlink there?

Comment: @HasanAbdulGhaffar Paste your desired link like  `href="www.youtube.com"` . I've updated the code . Do accept the answer if it helps ;-)